# Run a code for two telegram bots

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to enter two tokens in a code, that is, by executing the code, two telegram bots will work.My codes:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler
updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', token1='TOKEN1')

def start_method(bot,update):
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,"Hello")
start_command = CommandHandler('start', start_method)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.start_polling()
```

When I Run these code, it will error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/python2.7.9/dsdad.py", line 2, in <module>
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', token1='TOKEN1')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token1'
```

How can I do this?So that by inserting two tokens into the codes, the codes will run for both telegram bots ??

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by simply adding the bot code you want to use into the function. Than you can pass the two bots using threads into the function.

```
from threading import Thread
```

and then you place the threads as so, with xxxxxxxx being your bot code:

```
Thread(target=start_method, args=(xxxxxxxxx, )).start()
```